# OnTouchListener view is always the same

Tags: android, android-view, ontouchlistener

I have an Activity which implements `OnTouchListener`.  I then have a couple of custom view that are registered to this.

```
customView1.setOnTouchListener(this);
customView2.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

I then have this:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            if (view == customView1); {

                t = Toast.makeText(this, "customView1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
}
```

The problem is that the Toast is shown even when the view clicked is not customView1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `View.getId()` to get `onTouch` on different view instead of comparing instance's :

```
   if (view.getId() == customView1.getId()) {

        t = Toast.makeText(this, "customView1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }
```

and also remove `semicolon(;)` after if condition to execute if block

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon right after if statement. So if condition is useless in your case.

So remove ; after below statement

```
 if (view == customView1);
```